# В форме есть вложенные формы связных моделей. Как их валидировать?

Tags: php, jquery, yii

У меня есть форма (генерируется по модели `user`)
Есть связные таблицы `1:М`. У юзера может быть `n` мейлов, `n` адресов и т.д.
Данные валидации возвращаются в таком виде:

```
{"errors":{
    "CPerson_lname":["Last name cannot be blank."],
    "CPersonEmail_0_email":["Email cannot be blank."]
}}
```

`CPerson_lname` корректно обрабатывается и валидация обновляется, но всё, что касается ошибок валидации связных данных - ничего не происходит. Итак, как это реализовать ПРАВИЛЬНО? Костыльнуть как - я знаю =)

Comment: Самое простое отказаться от AJAX. Тогда можно сгенерировать поля и вывести ошибки для каждого.

Answer (score 1):

используй кнопку submit для каждой формы отдельно, потом по ее нажатию вешаешь поиск родителя например

```
$(document).on('.submit', 'click', function(e) {
var form = $(this).parents('form');
form.validate();
if(form.valid)
form.submit();
return false;
});
```